# MessageBox.Show not working with my visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Hello I'm practicing on typing codes of inventory system of products for the pos software.
 I'm working on something like here:

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFMw8.png) to see my products of inventory sketch.

And after a click on the save button for the results of the database then it should show up like the "record added...." window. And I don't see the result even I don't see any error on my visual studio pro software.

And please let me know which part is wrong and how to fix that.

Here is my code of salesn.cs file

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace superpos3
{
    public partial class salesn : Form
    {
        public salesn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int totalPrice = 0;

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server= localhost; database =superpos;  username= root; password=; ");
        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txtno_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            {
                txtqty.Enabled = true;
                txtqty.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void txtqty_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            {

                try
                {

                    string txt = "select * from products where id='" + txtno.Text + "'";
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(txt, con);
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (r.Read())
                    {
                        int price = int.Parse(txtqty.Text.ToString()) * int.Parse(r[4].ToString());
                        totalPrice = totalPrice + price;
                        //discount
                        // totalPrice = totalPrice - totalPrice* Payment.discount/100;

                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.RowCount, r[0], r[1], txtqty.Text.Trim(), r[4], price);

                    }
                    lbitems.Text = " " + (dataGridView1.RowCount - 1) + "";
                    lbtotal.Text = " " + totalPrice + " ";

                    con.Close();

                }






                catch (Exception ee)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ee.Message, "Error From Database");
                }

                txtno.Focus();
                txtno.Clear();

                txtqty.Enabled = false;
                txtqty.Clear();

            }

        }


        private void txtqty_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void salesn_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbldate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            lbltime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

            con.Open();
            string query = "select max(id) from salesmain ";
            MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
            MySqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                string val = dr[0].ToString();
                if (val == "")
                {
                    lbinvoice.Text = "1";

                }
                else
                {
                    int a;

                    a = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
                    a = a + 1;
                    lbinvoice.Text = a.ToString();



                }
                con.Close();
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = con;

                    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into salesproducts(saleid,productname,qty,price,grosstotal)values(@salesid,@productname,@qty,@price,@grosstotal)";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@saleid", lbinvoice.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grosstotal", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);

                    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand();
                    cmd1.Connection = con;
                    cmd1.CommandText = "insert into salesmain(id,date,time,qty,grosstotal)values(@id,@date,@time,@qty,@grosstotal)";
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lbinvoice.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", lbldate.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", lbltime.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", lbitems.Text);

                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grosstotal", lbtotal.Text);

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Record added ..........");
                    con.Close();












                }
               }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
           }
       }   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Aside from anything else, currently you're swallowing all exceptions. You have a commented-out `MessageBox.Show` call, but it's not going to be useful while it's commented out. That would be the *first* thing to change - and run the code in a debugger to see what's happening. Your question would also be better if you could tidy up the formatting and ideally reduce it to a *minimal* example... currently there's a lot of code there, and I suspect only a small amount of it is relevant to the question.

Comment: Note that your query (in the method `txtqty_KeyPress()`) is vulnerable to SQL injections. Consider using [parameterized queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_Parameters.htm) the same way you did in `button1_Click()`

Comment: Your query `cmd` from the method `button1_Click()` has a typo about the parameters name. `... values(@salesid, ...` versus `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@saleid", ...`. The parameter name in the query contains an S `@saleSid` while the parameter added doesn't

Comment: yes, it is right. Thank you @Cid it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should check if the dataGridView1.Rows.Count is not zero because if it is, the for loop won't even run which means that neither your code nor the message box show method is gonna run.

the other MessageBox.Show() methods are inside catch blocks which obviously means that they won't run if the catch block doesn't catch any errors.